Let $X(t)$ be a Gaussian process. Does $\mathbb{E}[X(t)^2 X(s)^2] = \mathbb{E}[X(t)^2 ] \mathbb{E}[X(s)^2 ] + 2 (\mathbb{E}[X(t) X(s)])^2 $?
As the title says, can I apply Isserlis' theorem to $\mathbb{E}[X(t)X(t)X(s)X(s)]$?

Yes. $(X(t),X(t),X(s),X(s))$ is a 4-variate Gaussian distribution, so Isserlis' theorem applies to it.

Thank you! It makes sense now how it would fit into the theorem as stated on Wikipedia.
